# How to impose a limit by using ServerValue.increment() in firebase realtimedatabase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to mobile android development. I am trying to build an library management application. Here I have two admins ,who can modify the bookCount in the database (realtime database, firebase) by clicking on a button "add". I want to impose a restriction on bookCount that it shouldn't exceed 50 i.e if current bookCount is 35 and both the admins want to increase by 6 and 10 each, then it must handle any one request but not both. I tried the following code to code impose that condition:(result should be either 35+6 or 35+10 but not 35+6+10)

```
   public void onClick(View view) {
    String isbn=isbnNo.getText().toString();
    int books= Integer.parseInt(addBooks.getText().toString());
    DatabaseReference ref=reference.child("books").child(isbn).child("bookCount");//line 52
  ref.setValue(ServerValue.increment(books)).addOnCompleteListener((Activity) getApplicationContext(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });}
```

My database looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPj2J.png)

I modified the rules like this:

```
    {
      "rules": {
  "books":{
    "$isbn":{
      ".write": "newData.hasChildren(['authorName', 'bookCount','bookName','isbn','price'])",
        "bookCount":{
        ".validate":"newData.isNumber()&& newData.val()>=0 && newData.val<50"
        }
    }
  }
```

}
}

Logcat ouput:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at com.example.librarymanagementsystem.updateBookCount.onClick(updateBookCount.java:53)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25919) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6826) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Upon clicking the button add, the value in the database is increasing but immediately my app is crashing. I think its because of Task, but I am not sure.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The documentation on [data validation in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules) has some good examples, so I recommend you start with that. If you're having trouble making it work for your use-case, I recommend showing what you've tried already.

Comment: Thanks, this documentation has helped, but now I have problem in showing appropriate toast message i.e whether the increment has been done or not. When I tried with addOnCompleteListener , my app is crashing.

Comment: 1) Please show your security rules as text, not as a screenshot. 2) if the app crashes, what is the error message and stack trace you get in the logcat output?

Comment: It shows classCastException

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: line 53 , ref.setValue(ServerValue.increment(books).addOncompleteListener -- this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code is failing `(Activity) getApplicationContext()`, so that indicates that `getApplicationContext()` is not returning an `Activity`.

I recommend removing that part of the call, and just calling:

```
ref.setValue(ServerValue.increment(books))
   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
       ...
```